# USB 3.0 randomly disconnecting and reconnecting

Tags: windows-8, usb, external-hard-drive

I had an old laptop that died so I have bought a new one. I have taken the 2.5 SATA hard drive from the old laptop and I have put it into an external 2.5 SATA enclosure usb 3.0 and I connect it to the new laptop.
My new laptop has Windows 8 64 bit installed. When I connect the external hard drive to the new laptop throught USB 3.0 port, it gets randomly disconnecting and reconnecting continuously, even when I am not using it. Also happens if I connect to another usb 3.0 port.
Also I have observed that If I connect the external hard drive to a USB 2.0 port instead of an USB 3.0 port all work ok, no randomly disconnection and reconnection occurs. It only happens when I connect it to an USB 3.0 port.

Some ideas to solve this issue?

Comment: I was having this same issue (`HP Probook 4540s, Windows 8.1 64bit`) and tried several solutions given by different forums. Finally got this and solved my problem. http://plugable.com/2012/12/01/windows-8-and-intel-usb-3-0-host-controllers

Answer (score 9):

This is typically due to a power configuration option. Go into device manager and don't allow the computer to put the device to sleep!

[image]

If this doesn't work, try playing with the power options in Control Panel

Comment: Ok, I'll try it later when I come back home and I'll tell you something here(now I am at work and I can't), but I wonder why it happens with USB 3.0 only and not for USB 2.0 (USB 2.0 works).

Comment: @user1624552 - USB 3.0 is able to draw a great deal more power.  Its likely a power saving option that the OEM decided was worth enabling by default.

Comment: @user1624552 did it work or not?

Comment: This worked for me. Why did the OS figured it was a good idea to turn off an USB 3 HDD while in the middle of copying gigabytes of data in order to save power is completely beyond me, though.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me is to use a shorter cord!
It turns out that USB 3.0 isn't designed to work on cords much longer than a meter, and my 6 footer was causing quite a few problems.
Smaller cord = no/less lost connections.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in addition to the setting above.
Go to:

- control panel
- power options
- change plan settings
- change advanced power settings
- USB settings
- USB selective suspend setting
  The set the plugged in option to *disabled*.

Answer (score 1):

Go into your BIOS settings and look for "Legacy USB Support" and DISABLE IT or TURN OFF.

Resolved ALL of my USB 3.0 problems and is even about 40% faster then before (when it was working and before it reset).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved by connecting a usb3 hub between the computer and the hard drive. No problem for two weeks now.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and I'm pretty sure it is due to the cheap laptop I'm using not providing sufficient power to the USB 3.0 port. When I use a powered USB to SATA adapter or plug in the unpowered cable through a powered USB hub the drive works just fine.

When I plug it in directly the drive disconnects when I copy data which I assume is due to increased powered draw from the drive.

Oh, it also works fine when plugged directly into my Alienware laptop with the unpowered cable.