# External hard drive (USB 3.0) disconnects after half an hour when robocopy is copying large files

Tags: windows-10, drivers, file-transfer, usb-3, robocopy

I'm constantly facing the same issue, that I'm not able to successfully copy files from one internal drive to an external drive. I'm using `robocopy` with this command

```
robocopy D:\ F:\ /e /zb /np /copy:DAT /dcopy:T /r:2 /w:5 /mir /log+:C:\Users\SomeUser\Desktop\Logs\copy.log /XD "System Volume Information" "Recycler"
```

After half an hour the command windows disappears as well as the hard drive from explorer. Some files were copied, but the transfer aborted in the middle. The event viewer shows the following entries in descending order:

> Event ID 140/Ntfs:
>   Die Daten konnten nicht in das Transaktionsprotokoll
>   verschoben werden. Die Daten sind möglicherweise beschädigt:
>   Volume-ID: "F:", Gerätename: "\Device\HarddiskVolume10".
>   ({Gerät-Zeitüberschreitung} Das Zeitlimit des angegebenen E/A-Vorgangs
>   auf %hs wurde erreicht, bevor der E/A-Vorgang abgeschlossen wurde.)
>
> Event ID 140/Ntfs:
>   Die Daten konnten nicht in das Transaktionsprotokoll
>   verschoben werden. Die Daten sind möglicherweise beschädigt:
>   Volume-ID: "F:", Gerätename: "\Device\HarddiskVolume10". (Ein nicht
>   vorhandenes Gerät wurde angegeben.)
>
> Event ID 51/Disk:
>   Bei einem Auslagerungsvorgang wurde ein Fehler
>   festgestellt. Betroffen ist Gerät \Device\Harddisk2\DR3.
>
> Event ID 153/Disk:
>   Der E/A-Vorgang an der logischen Blockadresse "0x5b0958"
>   für den Datenträger "2" (PDO-Name: \Device\0000008d) wurde wiederholt.
>
> Event ID 129/UASPStor:
>   Ein Zurücksetzen auf Gerät "\Device\RaidPort3" wurde
>   ausgegeben.

One should be able to get the correct translation based on the event id.

Checkdisk doesn't show any errors

```
chkdsk F: /f /r
```

Other things I tried:

- use another cable
- use another USB 3.0 port (all directly on the motherboard)
- reboot
- disabled energy saving in device manager
- disabled energy saving for USB in power settings
- searched for "Legacy USB Support" in the BIOS settings, but didn't found one
- uninstalled "Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible-Hostcontroller - 1.0 (Microsoft)" driver

Nothing of this worked. The funny thing is, that this setup has worked in another similar configuration but with another operating system. Same motherboard, same hard drives, same external enclosure, ...

My bet is that the default Microsoft USB 3.0 driver is faulty. I event can't install another one, because Intel doesn't support Windows 10 ... Don't know why such a simple task cannot be done anymore with a modern operating system.

[Related](https://superuser.com/questions/586419/usb-3-0-randomly-disconnecting-and-reconnecting), but no solution worked for me. Searching the internet brings related threads - mostly with no real solution.

What is the problem causing this issue and how can I solve this?

**GSmartControl**

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   188   188   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       9600
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       147
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       762
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       58
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       17
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       587
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   124   116   000    Old_age   Always       -       28
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       36
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
```

**Byte comparison**

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo d:\ | findstr /I "bytes"
Bytes pro Sektor :                 512
Bytes pro physischem Sektor :      4096
Bytes pro Cluster :                4096
Bytes pro Dateidatensatzsegment :  1024

C:\WINDOWS\system32>fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo F:\ | findstr /I "bytes"
Bytes pro Sektor :                 512
Bytes pro physischem Sektor :      4096
Bytes pro Cluster :                4096
Bytes pro Dateidatensatzsegment :  1024
```

**Edit**

Now I used another external enclosure and the backup did work! I used the same USB cable, the same USB port, the same motherboard, the same operating system/machine, the same hard drive. Only the enclosure was different. To go more into detail:

- **Cremax Icy Dock MB080U3S-1SB Blizzard**
  Seems to use "ASMT 2105 USB Device" controller and works with the windows driver.
- **Fantec - MR-35DU3-6G**
  Seems to use "JMS56x" controller and doesn't work with the windows driver. The drive appears as `SCSI Disk Drive` and this case is able to use two hard drives at the same time. In my configuration only one hard drive was installed.

In the first place one would think that the external enclosure is faulty, but I can't fully believe this because it worked before. It also does work some time and then it fails with robocopy. When I scanned the device with checkdisk it stayed online the whole time. So I still believe this is an driver issue or a energy management thing. I didn't had this problem before, only with the new Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Check your external drive with GSmartControl, if attributes 5,196,197 greater than zero then external drive is dying

Comment: @Alex: Which attribute do you mean?

Comment: Sounds like power option. In device manager, find the usb, go to properties and check the options to see if you can stop it powering off

Comment: @Dave: Already tried that without success

Comment: any hard drive has embedded controller with its own memory that keep standardized statistics called S.M.A.R.T. when you would run gsmartcontrol (https://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.io/home/index.php/Downloads) it will "talk" to internal HDD's controller and will show health of HDD. Attributes I mentioned you would find in Gsmartcontrol program

Comment: @Alex: Which entry do you mean? Raw Read Error Rate, Spin-Up Time, ...

Comment: These are most important: Reallocated Sectors Count, Reallocation Event Count, Current Pending Sector Count, (Offline) Uncorrectable Sector Count, Soft Read Error Rate or
TA Counter Detected. GSmartControl would highlight in purple color attributes that out of normal range

Comment: Apparently, this has been a common issue since at least Windows 7 - see https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/usb-drive-disconnect-during-large-transfer-also/95edcf8e-3bc8-4e35-befd-9850aa5224d2  You might try an alternative: https://alternativeto.net/software/robocopy/?license=free&platform=windows

Comment: If you have access to any other usb drive, try it. Same issue?

Comment: @Alex: Now I have two of the same drives in my list, because with the external enclosure I was not able to read the SMART values. Can't really check which one is which, because the name is not shown. I would have to reboot and disconnect ... There is no purple background color with both drives. Some of the values stated doesn't make any sense to me. Perhaps for you?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT: No, there is no difference (see edited question).

Comment: If GSmartControl parameters you posted are really from external hard drive then this drive's health is perfectly fine. If you want to diagnose further to spot if this issue hardware related or software is in charge then I would download some live LinuxCD, mount both hard drives, primary one and external one and do coping that large file for test. If it finished copying successfully then an issue on windows size, otherwise, it something with hardware (cables, USB adapter on external drive, motherboard, etc...) Let me know if you want to try Linux, I will try to assist you how to do that easier.

Comment: @Dave: Now I used another enclosure and robocopy could finish the work. See edited question for more info.

Comment: @Alex: I tried another enclosure and it did work (see edited question). Do you have an idea what the difference is? Is it a driver issue as DrMoishe Pippik stated?

Comment: In most cases driver would be the same - "USB mass storage device", you can compare by checking properties of both external drives (right click on drive=>property=>hardware then select you drive and hit "property", on "general" tab there would name of windows driver it used for this device) If windows driver is the same for both, then most likely it's hardware issue with internal adapter USB-to-SATA inside enclosure or it could be a bad USB cable/connector.

Comment: Is there still a quetion then? You know how to solve it. As to if something is shorting or similar, I don't feel we can answer this without seeing it

Comment: @Alex: Under the "drivers" tab it's always the MS driver (v. 10.0.17134.1), because the hostcontroller does have the MS driver installed. I can't for sure eliminate that this isn't a hardware issue, but if it's a hardware issue it must be with the integrated controller in the enclosure. The setup has also been used shortly on another Win 10 machine with different USB driver only for reading purposes over longer periods without issues. I don't get why transfering large files on another machine does make issues. Checkdisk also worked without the drive disconnecting over USB  ...

Comment: @Dave: Yeah, it's kind of solved. At least I have a workaround now. I still believe the reason is another than the hardware issue though. What I can do next time is to connect over USB 2.0 only and see what happens. Then I could install the "hacked" driver for Win 10 and see what happens.